# Web application penetration testing resources?

Tags: web-application, penetration-test, professional-education

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best resources to learn web security attacks?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/13570/best-resources-to-learn-web-security-attacks)

I'm very interested in web application penetration testing. I went over every good Youtube video on that subject and most  of the books. I'm reading [Tangled web](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1593273886) at the moment. Thanks to those resources I've reported many vulnerabilities on sites in my country and had a chance to expand my knowledge and meet some cool people. If you know any valuable resources, free videos or free courses please post link here. Thank you very much.

Comment: Similar: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/13570/best-resources-to-learn-web-security-attacks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sans has a Web Penetration Testing and Ethical Hacking: Capture the Flag class you might be interested at

https://www.sans.org/security-training/web-penetration-testing-ethical-hacking-capture-flag-day-6-13632-cid

Another place to practice would be the sites listed at

http://captf.com/practice-ctf/